# How to fix Zscaler XDG under i3

Tags: xdg

I cannot authenticate to `Zscaler` on my Debian because XDG does not appear to be returning the auth token from the browser back to `Zscaler`. I'm pretty sure this is because I'm using `i3` instead of Gnome or KDE. i3 has no active participation with XDG (e.g. I need to use `dex` to run the things in `xdg/autostart`). I'm missing something...

The `Zscaler` installer puts the same `ZSTray.desktop` in both `/etc/xdg/autostart` and `/usr/share/applications` and XDG appears to be happy:

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/zsa
ZSTray.desktop
```

Once successfully authenticated, the browser attempts to return the token to `Zscaler` with this little `javascript` function:

```
    function launch() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            const queryString = window.location.search;
            const url = "zsa://token" + queryString;
            document.location.href = url;
        }, 500)
    }
```

Sadly, the URL `zsa://token...` does not appear to be forwarded back to `Zscaler`.

If I simply type "zsa://token" into the browser, there is a notification "Open Zscaler Client Connector? A web site wants to open this application."

Is there a way to debug the XDG communications? I'd like to confirm that the message is actually being "sent" and "received" by Zscaler or not.

Can someone suggest a test scenario? e.g. I'd love to try to send the token (taken from the javascript) manually on the command line; but I'm not sure how.